# using sed to delete two characters when they appear together but not individual one

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I would like to delete ./ in my file, but I also got . and / in my file by themselves, and those need to be kept. I only wanted to delete ./ as a combination. What would be the right sed code to do so?

Hope someone can help me out. I will really appreciate it. Thank you in advance!

Comment: We generally expect people asking for help here to demonstrate that they have made a good faith effort to solve the problem for themselves.  Usually that involves showing at least one plausible attempt at a solution.

Comment: And some sample inputs and expected outputs from those inputs ;-/

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't show Input_file to us, so I am assuming this could be your Input_file, kindly try following and let me know if this helps you.

```
cat Input_file
test ./ test . test./test. /test1/
./test . /test . / test/ test2 test3./ test4 . /
```

Following is the code with its output.

```
awk '{gsub(/\.\//,"");print}'  Input_file
test  test . testtest. /test1/
test . /test . / test/ test2 test3 test4 . /
```

**EDIT:** Adding a sed solution too now.

```
sed 's/\.\///g'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

In sed, one uses the `s` command to substitute text.

The general form is

> #### `s` `/` *pattern* `/` *replacement* `/` *flags*

- Our *pattern* is `\./` (to match a literal `.` followed immediately by `/`).
- Our *replacement* is nothing (empty string)
- Our *flags* is `g` (to replace every occurrence on the line).
- We can change the separator to `,` to avoid confusion with the `/` we're replacing.

Putting this into a complete sed program gives

```sed
#/usr/bin/sed -f
s,\./,,g
```

Alternatively, as a Bash one-liner

```sh
sed -e 's,\./,,g'
```